# Resize NSPopover does not update

Tags: xcode, cocoa, nspopover

I have an NSPopover where I change the content view of but when I set the view controller to something bigger than before, it shows the size that it was and I need to close and open it.

```
static func changeView(controller:  NSViewController) {
        let newSize = NSSize.init(width: controller.view.frame.size.width, height: controller.view.frame.size.height)
        popover.contentViewController = controller
        popover.contentSize = newSize
        //^ this does not update or whatever
}
```

[all code](https://pastebin.com/DnEW9FuB)

That is the code I use to change the view but it does not update the popover.

**EDIT**
It only resizes when I'm at my home screen but when I open it when Xcode is open fullscreen it doesn't work. :/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing nspopover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14378949/resizing-nspopover)

Comment: @Todd I doing that at the moment but it does not resize when animation is on or trying it in a fullscreen application.

Comment: Ok, personally, I've had no luck resizing `NSPopover`s so have had to resort to creating a new nib, view controller and duplicate code for each size of popover that I required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So to resize a NSPopover correctly you need to set animates to false like `AppDelegate.`.